# IE 11 no reconoce la definición de clases

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

En Chrome funciona perfectamente, pero con IE11 lanza un error de sintáxis en la línea con el código:

```
class Animation{...}
```

Parece ser que esta nueva característica del ECMAScript6 no es compatible con los demás navegadores. Según he probado y según dice la tabla de navegadores compatibles para `class`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes

¿Sabéis alguna solución provisional para usar las clases sin problemas en los demás navegadores? Una solución sería usar los prototypes en vez de las clases, pero vengo del C# y me resulta muy incómodo.

Comment: checka eso. https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa [babel](http://babeljs.io/) y compila tu código primero. Esto se traducirá a un código que usa el sistema de herencia por prototipos que es compatible hasta con las primeras versiones de EcmaScript.

Para instalarlo primero descarga [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Instala el paquete con `npm`

Puedes instalarlo global abriendo una consola y escribiendo

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

Pero es recomendado hacerlo por proyectos si ya estás usando `npm` como gestor de paquetes

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

Luego sólo invoca el `cli` pasandole el source de tus ficheros para que sean transformados

```
babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js
```

Ten en cuenta que

> Anterior a Babel 6.X ciertas transformaciones estaban activadas por defecto. Babel 6.x no habilita ninguna transformación. Debes decirle explicitamente que transformaciones ejecutar. La forma más sencilla de lograrlo es usando un preset, como el ES2015. Puedes instalarlo con
>
> `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`

Puedes usar herramientas como [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) para automatizar la conversión automática de tus sources o usar IDEs como [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) que lo traen incluido. En la sección [instalación](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) puedes seleccionar cuales herramientas usas y leer como integrarlas con babel.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas, me han ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 2):

En general, el soporte para ES6 aun no es completo y varía de un browser a otro. Puedes escribir tu aplicación en ES6 y usar [babel](https://babeljs.io/) o [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) para compilar (o transpilar) a ES5.

La configuración de esos compiladores puede tomar algún tiempo, pero luego puedes reusar esa configuración en otros proyectos. Además, hay varios tutoriales en la red.

Aunque si vines de C#, puede ser que te sientas más cómodo usando [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) en lugar de JavaScript, es un lenguaje que compila a JS